# глобальные переменные объекта

Tags: javascript, ооп

допустим, у меня есть объект с набором свойств и методов. при инициализации объекта метод method1 должен вывести в консоль свойство this.prop1. я могу поступить двумя способами:

1.

```
var Game = function() {
  this.prop1 = 1111;
  this.prop2 = 2222;

  this.method1(); 
};

Game.prototype = {
  method1: function() {   
    console.log(this.prop1);        
  }
};
```

2.

```
var Game = function() {
  this.prop1 = 1111;
  this.prop2 = 2222;

  this.method1(this.prop1); 
};

Game.prototype = {
  method1: function(prop1) {   
    console.log(prop1);        
  }
};
```

как видите, первый способ допускает использование 'глобальных' (в пределах объекта) переменных, второй - нет.

какой из них использовать будет правильнее? и главное почему?

я не могу определиться, у каждого способа есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: на этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначный ответ. Все зависит от того как будет использоваться метод в дальнейшем, а так же от содержания самого метода. Поэтому для текущего кода - нет разницы что использовать

Comment: честно говоря, я тоже так думаю. но мне главное услышать от опытных разработчиков, что оба способа рабочие и не велосипеды

Comment: не зная задачи, которую вы пытаетесь решить можно уверенно сказать что оба решения рабочие, или велосипеды :)

Comment: Вы не правильно употребляете термин "глобальный". Ваше свойство `Game.prop1` ни разу не глобальное ни в первом ни во втором примере. Использовать свойства объектов таким образом абсолютно нормально. Выбор между 1 и 2 должен определяться исключительно реальным назначением метода.

Comment: Что-то я вопрос понять не могу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда проектируете свое приложение, задумывайтесь о назначении инструментов и правильно ли Вы их используете. Вполне возможно, есть гораздо более простые и эффективные способы решения задачи.

Размещение в прототипах используется для исключения дублирования функций и переменных, которые потом будут использоваться в экземплярах объектов. То есть, когда Вам надо вызвать их с помощью объекта в дальнейшем.

Первый способ обращается только к своим внутренним свойствам и никогда не принимает внешние. То есть его надо использовать только тогда, когда вы не планируете передавать в функцию какие-то посторонние значения и используете только по отношению к конкретному экземпляру. Для задачи в вопросе он подходит лучше всего и его всегда можно вызвать повторно.

```
var Game = function() {
  this.prop1 = 1111;
  this.prop2 = 2222;

  this.info(); 
};

Game.prototype = {
  info: function() {   
    console.log("prop1: " + this.prop1 + "prop2: "+prop2);        
  }
};
var g = new Game(); 
g.info(); //мы снова получим информацию об объекте
```

Давайте рассмотрим второй способ.

```
var Game = function() {
  this.prop1 = 1111;
  this.prop2 = 2222;

  this.method1(this.prop1);
};

Game.prototype = {
  method1: function(prop1) {
    console.log(prop1);
  }
};

var g = new Game(); // -> выводит 1111
g.method1();        // -> выводит undefined
```

Итак, поздравляю, был создан одноразовый метод который абсолютно бесполезен в дальнейшем и торчит наружу. Конечно его можно вызвать повторно, но это не самое элегантное решение и не приносит никаких улучшений в код.

```
var g = new Game(); // -> выводит 1111
g.method1(g.prop1); // -> выводит 1111
```

Тогда какой смысл его запускать в прототип? В нем был бы смысл, если бы вы его использовали повторно и по назначению. К примеру, для создания каких-нибудь вспомогательных методов, которым потом действительно нужно передавать разные значения. Но для данных действий в вопросе он не годится.

Все равно, в обоих методах остается вопрос. Вы не используете его повторно, а используете единожды при инициализации, потому оба они не подходят для задачи в приведенном примере. Если надо, то более удачным следующий код, который исключит ненужное использование прототипа и закроет интерфейс торчащий наружу.

```
var Game = function() {
  this.prop1 = 1111;
  this.prop2 = 2222;

  (function(_this) { 
      console.log(_this.prop1); 
  })(this); 
};
```

Почитайте про принципы ООП и использование его принципов в JavaScript. Как производить инкапсуляцию, исключать дублирование, зачем нужно наследование и по каким правилам наследуются объекты, как исключать зависимости. Это касается и вашего [второго вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490880/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), где вы пытаетесь наследовать несвязанные сущности.

Comment: как-то вы по конкретному коду сделали вывод о всем способе :-) `console.log(prop1);` же наверняка для примера вставлен, а так как неизвестно содержимое метода, нельзя сказать что он полезен или бесполезен. Кроме того более удачный код опять же на конкретном примере был бы `console.log(this.prop1);` нет смысла его оборачивать в IIFE

Comment: @Grundy вообще я просто рассказал зачем нужен прототип и когда его стоит или не стоит использовать. Если речь о разовом действии при инициализации, то он вообще не нужен. Ну IIFE исключительно как имитация функции конструктора.

Comment: Просто сейчас по вашему ответу получается второй способ **никогда** нельзя использовать, а это не так

Comment: @Grundy постарался более развернуто ответить с рассмотрение что и когда использовать.