# возможна ли архитектура без наследования?

Tags: ооп, архитектура

допустим, есть игра, написанная в ООП-стиле. основной объект game порождает объект level. далее level порождает кучу объектов: танков, самолётиков, солдатиков и т.д. логично всё это организовать через наследование. это удобно, потому что, если солдатику понадобится какое-нибудь свойство из level или из game, то он его получит.

но можно обойтись без наследования. в этом случае придётся при создании объекта в конструктор передавать родительский объект. например, объекту level понадобилось имя игрока:

```
var Game = function() {
  this.username = 'petya'
  this.levelObj = new Level(this);   
};

var Level = function(gameObj) { 
  this.gameObj = gameObj;     
  this.method1();
};
Level.prototype = {   
  method1: function() { 
    console.log(this.gameObj.username);
  }
}
```

итак, существуют два способа организации кода: с использованием наследования(1) и без использования наследования(2).

вопрос. это два равноценных способа? или второй способ — это велосипед, который лучше не использовать, чтобы не запутаться на определённом этапе?

что вообще можно почитать на эту тему, хотя бы на английском языке? именно по организации кода мне редко попадаются хорошие ресурсы.

вопрос не привязываю к какому-либо языку, потому что он очень общий.

Comment: вообще говоря наследовать солдата от уровня - совсем не логично. и проблема скорее всего не в наследовании, а в общей архитектуре программы, таким образом стоит пересмотреть список используемых объектов и связей между ними

Comment: @cyklop77 Наследование как и вообще ООП модель данных должна отражать реальный мир. Наследование - это именно расширение свойств/поведения предка. Наследование "солдат" и "танк" от общего предка "боевая единица" логично, у боевой единицы может быть куча общих свойств позволяющих солдатам и танкам передвигаться по полю боя, например. А "уровень" явно внешнее от них понятие, танк никак функциональность уровня не раширяет. Уровень может содержать например массив всех боевых единиц, как свои свойства. А единица просто должна хранить свойство на каком уровне она находится, например

Comment: спасибо за ответы. но способ, код которого я привёл в вопросе, имеет право на существование? он не приведёт к гарантированному запутыванию логики когда проект станет большим?

Comment: Даже при правильной архитектуре можно запутаться. Просто внедряя новый функционал, задавайте себе вопрос, не будет ли проблем в будущем? Всегда продумывайте наперед, например, а что если у мне нужно будет через полгода добавить плавающие танки, смогу ли я быстро добавить такой функционал в текущую архитектуру. И да, читать материалы полезно, но прочитайте вы хоть 200 книг, без собственных наступаний на грабли вы не научитесь хорошо проектировать. Так что пробуйте, но всё же придерживайтесь правил, описанных выше пользователем Mike.

Comment: По идеи, должен быть 1 уровень (Level) и а нем n-количество техники, если технику наследовать от Level, то у каждого будет свой набор свойств Level. Можно конечно у Level создать фабричный метода для создания техники, но мне кажется такой подход не далеко не самым лучшим.

Comment: Для общего развития почитайте [Object-oriented programming languages are a major misstep; a tortuous detour that computer scientists should never have taken.](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/c/object.html) Это из статьи ["Ben Lin"](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~blynn/) (один из специалистов из Стенфорда)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя наследование в предлагаемом виде, вы нарушаете инкапсуляцию классов и добавляете сильную связность между ними. Это приведет в дальнейшем к сложности расширения/модификации кода и архитектуры приложения.

Наследование должно использоваться только когда выполняется отношение `is a`. Это значит, что производный объект в то же время является базовым, расширяя или изменяя его поведение.

Вы можете для начала использовать композицию:

- класс `Game` будет иметь список уровней `Level` и текущий активный уровень,
- класс `Level` будет иметь список текущих объектов.
- в классе `Object` определить методы доступа к нужным полям, с помощью которых и будет осуществляться обращение к свойствам объекта.
- при необходимости создания игрового объекта в зависимости от уровня ему задаются нужные параметры.